# Can't parse data from json

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to display a stacked bar chart on my web page, but it's not working.

---

I've tried to follow the documentation about data structure, but it seems not working. The two data are made from an Ajax call and built in js.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html

---

I've made a jsfiddle if you want to look at what I've done.

https://jsfiddle.net/batmine3/h4w02y5g/6/

```
let myData = [
    {
        x: 'value1',
    critical: 1,
    high: 2,
    medium: 0,
    low: 5  
    },
  {
        x: 'value2',
    critical: 2,
    high: 0,
    medium: 5,
    low: 0 
    }
];

let myLabels = ['value1', 'value2'];

let stackedBar = new Chart($('#chartContainer'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: myLabels,
    datasets: 
    [
      {
        label: 'critical',
        data: myData,
        borderColor: '#d30000',
        backgroundColor: '#d30000',
        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 'critical'
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'high',
        data: myData,
        borderColor: '#e97000',
        backgroundColor: '#e97000',
        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 'high'
        }
      }, 
      {
        label: 'medium',
        data: myData,
        borderColor: '#ff9c56',
        backgroundColor: '#ff9c56',
        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 'medium'
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'low',
        data: myData,
        borderColor: '#ffd063',
        backgroundColor: '#ffd063',
        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 'low'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        ridLines: {
            display: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after, investigating styles and formatting, it was just a problem of versions.
The parse options were not present in version 2.8.